# WPF Design view in Visual Studio 2010--scroll the scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, preview, scrollviewer

I just added a `ScrollViewer` to my WPF app.  Now some of my content is hidden because it is at the bottom of the `ScrollViewer`--this is intentional.  However, is there any way in the Design view of Visual Studio 2010 to scroll a scrollbar so that I can preview what my app looks like when the scrollbar is at different positions?  It would be convenient to check this out without having to build my Solution and run my app, just to scroll down and make sure things look as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `ScrollViewer` is contained in a `UserControl` that does not have a height set on it.  I set my `ScrollViewer`'s height to `Auto` so all the contents of the `ScrollViewer` show in Design view in my `UserControl`--this way, I can see what I'm doing.  I set the height of the `Window` that includes the `UserControl`, so when I run my app the `ScrollViewer` is bounded by that `Window` height, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed these properties from my `UserControl` in Visual Studio.

`d:DesignHeight` and `d:DesignWidth`

Like yours, my ScrollViewer's height was already set to Auto.